# Múltiples ventanas modales

Tags: javascript, html, modal, popup

buen día, mi problema es el siguiente, quiero crear una ventana tipo pop up donde cada vez que se le da un clic se abra la la imagen puesta en el html.
adjunto una liga de codepen con una mini prueba.
si funciona abrir y cerrar el modal, pero sólo abre el último modal creado.
Quisiera saber si existe un mejor modo de hacerlo para así poner infinitas imágenes con poco contenido de script.
muchas gracias

[prueba modal](https://codepen.io/aldo-micilio-deotro/pen/EdLVEm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas especificar el contexto con `this` asi:

```
$(document).ready(abrir);
function abrir(){
    $('.modal-btn').click(function(){
        if($(this).find('.modal-contenido').hasClass('reposo')){
            $(this).find('.modal-contenido').removeClass('reposo').addClass('activo'),$('body').css({
                overflow: 'hidden',
            });
        }else{
            $(this).find('.modal-contenido').removeClass('activo').addClass('reposo'),$('body').css({
                overflow: 'visible'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: gracias! me ayudaste un montón